# I can't get my Shiny (in R) app scatterplot to render in the window

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

An error that keeps coming up is `Error in output$barchart <- renderPlotly({ : object 'output' not found`

I'm not quite sure what's going wrong here. I'm just kind-of overwhelmed by this project.

I'm doing this project using the Midwest dataframe that is pre-loaded in dplyr

I'm open to any edits anyone has on this. Aghghhhgghgh helppppp lol

Here's my two files so far (server.R and ui.R)

Server:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(lintr)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)
library(tidyverse)
library(operators)
library(magrittr)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
output$barchart <- renderPlotly({

scatter <- ggplot(data = midwest, 
         mapping = aes(x = percollege, y = percpovertyknown)) + 
    geom_point(aes(fill = state, size = popdensity), shape = 21, color = "white") + 
  #  geom_smooth(aes(x = percollege, y = percpovertyknown)) +
    labs(
      x = "Percent with college education", 
      y = "Poverty rate", 
      title = "Midwest Data",
      subtitle = "States with higher college education rates tend to have lower poverty rates") + 
    scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1") + 
    scale_size(range = c(0, 12)) +
    guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(col = "black")), 
           fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 5))) +
    theme_bw()
  chartly <- ggplotly(scatter)
  return(chartly)

})
  }
```

ui:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(lintr)

page_one <- tabPanel(
  "Introduction",
ui <-  fluidPage(

# START OF PAGE 2 / CHART---------------------------------
# Inputting Panel
page_two_sidepanel <- sidebarPanel(
  checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup",
                     label = h3("Select State"), 
                     choices = list("Illinois" = "IL",
                                    "Indiana" = "IN",
                                    "Minnesota" = "MN",
                                    "Ohio" = "OH",
                                    "Wisconsin" = "WN"),
                     selected = "IL"
  )
),

page_two_mainpanel <- mainPanel(
  h2("Barchart Comparison by Income Classification"), 
  plotOutput(
    outputId = "barchart"
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't able to reproduce the error you've faced, the code run just fine in my end. For simplicity sake, I made the code into a single app.R file. The one issue I found is it should be plotlyOutput instead of plotOutput.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(lintr)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)
library(tidyverse)
library(operators)
library(magrittr)
library(plotly)

    ui <-  fluidPage(
        

            checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup",
                               label = h3("Select State"), 
                               choices = list("Illinois" = "IL",
                                              "Indiana" = "IN",
                                              "Minnesota" = "MN",
                                              "Ohio" = "OH",
                                              "Wisconsin" = "WN"),
                               selected = "IL"
            ),
            plotOutput(
                outputId = "barchart"
            )
        )
    
    
        ui <- fluidPage(
            sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                    checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup",
                                       label = h3("Select State"), 
                                       choices = list("Illinois" = "IL",
                                                      "Indiana" = "IN",
                                                      "Minnesota" = "MN",
                                                      "Ohio" = "OH",
                                                      "Wisconsin" = "WN"),
                                       selected = "IL"
                    )
                ),
                mainPanel(
                    plotlyOutput("barchart")
                )
            )
        )


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$barchart <- renderPlotly({
        
        scatter <- ggplot(data = midwest, 
                          mapping = aes(x = percollege, y = percpovertyknown)) + 
            geom_point(aes(fill = state, size = popdensity), shape = 21, color = "white") + 
            #  geom_smooth(aes(x = percollege, y = percpovertyknown)) +
            labs(
                x = "Percent with college education", 
                y = "Poverty rate", 
                title = "Midwest Data",
                subtitle = "States with higher college education rates tend to have lower poverty rates") + 
            scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1") + 
            scale_size(range = c(0, 12)) +
            guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(col = "black")), 
                   fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 5))) +
            theme_bw()
        chartly <- ggplotly(scatter)
        return(chartly)
        
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```